# Check proof that, if $0 < k_1 < t_1$, $k_{n+1}= \sqrt{k_nt_n}$ and $t_{n+1}=(k_n+t_n)/2$, then $0\leq t_{n+1}- k_{n+1} \leq (t_1-k_1)/2^n$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification

> Let $0 < k_1 < t_1$  and for every integer $n \geq 1$, set $k_{n+1}= \sqrt{k_nt_n}$ and $t_{n+1}=(k_n+t_n)/2$.
>
> Prove that $0\leq t_{n+1}- k_{n+1} \leq (t_1-k_1)/2^n$ for every integer $n \geq 1$.

This is what I'm thinking...

Given that $0 < k_1 < t_1$, $k_{n+1}= \sqrt{k_nt_n}$, $t_{n+1}=(k_n+t_n)/2$, $\forall n \mathbb{N}$, consider $t_{n+1} - k_{n+1}$.

Then $$t_{n+1} - k_{n+1} = (k_n + t_n)/2 - k_{n+1}\\ =\frac{t_n+k_n-2k_{n+1}}{2}\\= \frac{t_n + k_n -k_{n+1} -k_{n+1}}{2}$$

Since $k_n \leq k _{n+1} \leq t _{n+1} \leq t_n$, $\forall n \in N$ (proved in earlier problem). Then $k_n-k_{n+1} \leq 0$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $-k_{n+1} \leq -k_n$,  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Therefore, $$t_{n+1} - k_{n+1} \leq \frac{t_n-k_n}{2} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{t_{n-1}+k_{n-1}}{2}-k_n)\\= \frac{1}{2}(\frac{t_{n-1}+k_{n-1}-2k_n}{2})\\= \frac{1}{2}(\frac{t_{n-1}+k_{n-1}-k_n-k_n}{2})$$

Since $k_{n-1} - k_n \leq 0$ and $=-k_n \leq -k_{n-1}$, then $t_{n+1}-k_{n+1} \leq \frac{t_{n-1} - k_{n-1}}{2^2}$.

If we continue this process, then $$t_{n+1} - k_{n+1} \leq \frac{t_{n-1}-k_{n-1}}{2^2} ...\leq \frac{t_2-k_2}{2^{n-1}} \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}(\frac{t_1+k_1}{2}-k_2)\\=\frac{t_1+k_1-2k_2}{2^n}\\=\frac{t_1+k_1-k_2-k_2}{2^n}$$

Since $k_1-k_2 \leq 0$ and $-k_2 \leq k_1$, then $t_{n+1} - k_{n+1} \leq (t_1 - k_1)/2^n$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Since $t_{n+1} \geq k_{n+1}$, then $0 \leq t_{n+1} - k_{n+1}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Therefore, $0 \leq t_{n+1} - k_{n+1} \leq \ (t_1-k_1)/2^n$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Would this be the correct proof?

Comment: how have you proved $k_n \leq k _{n+1} \leq t _{n+1} \leq t_n$?

Comment: I proved it in a previous question.